# Error while trying to install Plastic SCM on Debian

Tags: installation, plasticscm

good afternoon,

I am trying to install Plastic SCM version : PlasticSCM-4.1.10.454-linux-installer on a Debian 7 machine, and while installing, I get the following error :

(main.tcl:4735): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: value "1.002469" of type `gdouble' is invalid or out of range for property`fraction' of type `gdouble'

I have been looking through and througout google, and I still havent found a solution on this matter.

Has anyone encountered such an error?.

To me, (please excuse my unexperience), it seems to be an error returned by plastic SCM itself, not by the operative system... but I could be wrong.

Right now, i am downloading a past version : PlasticSCM-3.0.187.38-linux-installer , in an attempt to successfully install and  start learning to use Plastic SCM.

But, this is only a temporal fix, as I want to install the latest version and enjoy its full and current capabilities.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: We've created native packages for Debian. I'll share here the instructions to setup the repo asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to uninstall whatever Plastic SCM version installed on your machine.

Then follow the instructions to get Plastic SCM installed using the newest packages system. Don't worry about the "Debian_6.0" name, it works fine with the 7 release.

- Add our public repository to your APT sources list:

  echo "deb http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/4.1/Debian_6.0/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
- Add the key to the repository into APT

  wget http://www.plasticscm.com/plasticrepo/4.1/Debian_6.0/Release.key
  apt-key add Release.key
- Refresh the APT cache

  apt-get update
- Install PlasticSCM

  apt-get install plasticscm-client plasticscm-server

If you have any question don't hesitate to use the Plastic SCM forum -> www.plasticscm.net

Comment: Thank you for the feedback MrCatacroquer.